# How to point a windows web server subdir to a Centos server subdir permanently?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, wordpress

Here's the scenario.

We have a Windows 2003 Web Server (oursite.com) that serves our site (I know, sorry.) I use a Centos server to serve a lot of content into that main site (oursitelabs.com).

The oursite.com DNS is managed by Network Solutions (again, I know) and I manage the outsitelabs.com directly through MediaTemple.

I have setup a Wordpress MU installation on the Centos server in the domain root. I would like several blogs there oursitelabs.com/media-relations for example to be accessible at oursite.com/media-relations. We need for the visible uris to always be oursite.com/media-relations/whatever-the-post-is even though the area is physically hosted at oursitelabs.com.

Any advice on how to setup DNS/Windows/Centos/Wordpress to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up either a reverse proxy (so that the webserver at oursite.com will proxy content from oursitelabs.com) or you could set up a 302 for those urls at oursite.com so they get redirected to the appropriate oursitelabs.com.   Another possibility would be to do something tricky with frames on oursite.com so that it 'frames' the content from oursitelabs.com. Or do something funky with having the oursite.com page request content from oursitelabs.com via AJAX. The effects in each case are slightly different, but they'll all work to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly the only way I see this happening is if you setup a reverse proxy under IIS on Windows.  I don't have a lot of details as how to do this in IIS, but under Apache you could do it with mod_proxy/mod_rewrite (or similar module).

A quick google search brings up the following for IIS....

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/urlrewriter

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not really easy without adding extra components. The reverse is very easy. It really would be much simpler to point the DNS entry to the Centos server and have Apache proxy the requests for the IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

You need the IIS equivalent of this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

I would install Apache 2.2 for Windows on that server, set up on port 80.  I would then move IIS to another port (81?) and set up mod_proxy rules on a per-request basis.  If they request /media-relations/, then proxy the requests to your CentOS/labs machine.  If they request all else, proxy the requests to http://localhost:81/.

There appear to be a few options like ISAPI_Rewrite available for IIS itself, but I do not have any actual experience using them.